# What does this ansible-vault format mean?

Tags: ansible-2.x, ansible-vault

I am reverse-engineering and refactoring ansible code from a developer who has since left the company. In our ansible-vault file, I would love to know what the following items mean and how they add function/value to the yaml--I can't find any documentation in my search:
"base: &base"
"<<: *base"

Here is my sanitized vault yaml

```
---
secrets:
  zk:
    password: sdsfl34hgf
  admin:
    password: ldfk43277k
credentials:
  base: &base
    host: "{{ansible_host}}"
    timeout: 30
    transport: cli
  svc_rhelsystemro:
    <<: *base
    username: svc_rhelsystemro
    password: sdsfl34hgf
  svc_rhelsystemrw:
    <<: *base
    username: svc_rhelsystemrw
    password: ldfk43277k
  svc_Network_Automation:
    username: svc_Network_Automation
    password: slk32sd@#$%h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you were able to find your answer by now, but I'll post it here for anyone else looking for the same info.

What you are seeing are YAML anchors: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#yaml-anchors-and-aliases-sharing-variable-values.

I haven't personally used this functionality, but it essentially allows you to define aliases for complicated structures. In your example `base.host`, `base.timeout`, and `base.transport` can all be referenced at the same time using the `*base` alias.